# Elasticsearch- sort geo_distance filter returns 500

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, geolocation

my objective is narrowing down nearby addresses within 100 meters and sorting them by the nearest address

My mapping:

```
mappings: {
    dynamic: "true",
    properties: {
      geometry: { type: "geo_shape" }
    }
  }
```

The geo_shape is always a point

```
type: "point",
coordinates: [lat, long]
```

The query:

```
GET addresses/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "distance": "100",
          "geometry": {
            "lat": 51.3606,
            "lon": 7.4785
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_geo_distance": {
        "geometry": {
          "lat": 51.3606,
          "lon": 7.4785
        },
        "order": "asc",
        "unit": "m",
        "mode": "min",
        "distance_type": "arc",
        "ignore_unmapped": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**The query works without the sorting**

The error occurs only when I add the sorting to the query.

The query produces the following error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "class_cast_exception",
        "reason" : "class org.elasticsearch.xpack.spatial.index.fielddata.plain.AbstractLatLonShapeIndexFieldData$LatLonShapeIndexFieldData cannot be cast to class org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexGeoPointFieldData (org.elasticsearch.xpack.spatial.index.fielddata.plain.AbstractLatLonShapeIndexFieldData$LatLonShapeIndexFieldData is in unnamed module of loader java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader @28e94c2; org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexGeoPointFieldData is in unnamed module of loader 'app')"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "all shards failed",
    "phase" : "query",
    "grouped" : true,
    "failed_shards" : [
      {
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "addresses",
        "node" : "6ncZ_x83Qw2fnlzYvbcRzQ",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "class_cast_exception",
          "reason" : "class org.elasticsearch.xpack.spatial.index.fielddata.plain.AbstractLatLonShapeIndexFieldData$LatLonShapeIndexFieldData cannot be cast to class org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexGeoPointFieldData (org.elasticsearch.xpack.spatial.index.fielddata.plain.AbstractLatLonShapeIndexFieldData$LatLonShapeIndexFieldData is in unnamed module of loader java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader @28e94c2; org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexGeoPointFieldData is in unnamed module of loader 'app')"
        }
      }
    ],
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "class_cast_exception",
      "reason" : "class org.elasticsearch.xpack.spatial.index.fielddata.plain.AbstractLatLonShapeIndexFieldData$LatLonShapeIndexFieldData cannot be cast to class org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexGeoPointFieldData (org.elasticsearch.xpack.spatial.index.fielddata.plain.AbstractLatLonShapeIndexFieldData$LatLonShapeIndexFieldData is in unnamed module of loader java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader @28e94c2; org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexGeoPointFieldData is in unnamed module of loader 'app')",
      "caused_by" : {
        "type" : "class_cast_exception",
        "reason" : "class org.elasticsearch.xpack.spatial.index.fielddata.plain.AbstractLatLonShapeIndexFieldData$LatLonShapeIndexFieldData cannot be cast to class org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexGeoPointFieldData (org.elasticsearch.xpack.spatial.index.fielddata.plain.AbstractLatLonShapeIndexFieldData$LatLonShapeIndexFieldData is in unnamed module of loader java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader @28e94c2; org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexGeoPointFieldData is in unnamed module of loader 'app')"
      }
    }
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Isn't it possible to sort on geo_shape of type `point`?

Comment: Why are you indexing geometry field as geo_shape instead of geo_point? [_geo_distance sort does not support geo_shape](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/68953).

Comment: This is the reason
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/difference-between-geo-point-and-geo-shape-point/16477/2

Comment: That post is from 2014 and is no longer accurate. Elasticsearch has completely changed the way geo_point and geo_shape fields are indexed. See https://www.elastic.co/blog/bkd-backed-geo-shapes-in-elasticsearch-precision-efficiency-speed for details

Comment: Since you only have point data, I would recommend indexing data as geo_point